Old user interface ( object data properties ) for Blender 4.0?
Is it possible to get the older interface of the tab Object data properties for Blender 4.0? It's the main reason i never use newest blenders , i'm mostly intestred by the older Skeleton layers system :


Old Bone bit layers have been replaced by Bone Collections in all future versions of Blender. It is best if you learn the new system going forward since it is here to stay and is objectively better in most ways.

1- It's factually worse than the preview one

2- I did not ask your opinion on the subject

@ShuLien022 The system has been replaced, so no you can't get the older interface back because it works different now. If you prefer the old system, stick to older Blender versions. "It's factually worse" - well, now this your opinion. You're not a fan of hearing other's opinions either, are you? Have a good day.

1- You are wrong , you can get old interfaces with addons it's not uncommon , do not speak of things you have no knowledge of

2- Do not reverse the roles , i will correct anyone who will try to impose their opinions to me , even more when they are wrong.

If you don't know , do not reply to this post , you have been warned and i will not repeat myself.
